# Nested Outlets in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

My router:

```
App.Router.map( function() {
  this.resource('overview', {path: "/overview"}, function(){
    this.route('standard', {path: "/overview/standard"});
  });
});
```

Application Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application"> 
    <div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">

        <hgroup>
            <header>
                <div id="sessionInfo">
                </div>
            </header>
        </hgroup>

        {{partial Nav}}

        <div id="content" class="clearfix">

            {{outlet}}

        </div>

    </div>
</script>
```

Overview Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="overview">

    <div class="Box">
        <img id="disBox" src="blah.png" />
    </div>

    {{outlet}}

</script>
```

Standard Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="standard">

    <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background: blue; float: right;"></div>

</script>
```

Can I not have an outlet inside another outlet, or what am I missing here, the standard template never gets loaded to the page when I am at the url: index.html#/overview/standard

Answer (score 0):

Needed to indicate path in the data-template-name attribute like so:

Standard Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="overview/standard">

    <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background: blue; float: right;"></div>

</script>
```